# Add text to already existing text without replacing it in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Trying to make a calculator in Actionscript 3 where i click on the number buttons to add numbers to a textfield. However i am unable to add new numbers to the textfield without replacing the already existing number in the textfield.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. Please **edit** your question to add the code that represents your endeavor in solving your problem.

Comment: Maybe try using **String** to create text of pressed numbers. A string can be concat by using `+=`. Then send String to the **Textfield** for display.

Answer (score 1):

to add the test to an AS3 `TextField` you need the [`appendText()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#appendText()) method